# How to automatically select the nugget parameter in Gaussian process regression (GPR)?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, gaussian-process

In sklearn's [GPR](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html) function, how can I automatically determine the nugget parameter? It does not seem to be implemented within the package. Any insights are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The [nugget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variogram#Variogram_parameters), as it is called in geostatistics, corresponds to the [White-noise kernel](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.WhiteKernel.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.WhiteKernel) in sklearn. If your kernel includes a "nugget" term, its noise-level parameter will be automatically calibrated (via [mle](/questions/tagged/mle)) by the [fit()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.fit) method of a [GaussianProcessRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.html) estimator.

For details, see the example "[GPR with noise-level estimation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gpr_noisy.html)" in the sklearn docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any general hyperparameter selection such as Grid Search.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html

Comment: can the GridCV function be used together with GPR?